# Do you know what plant it is?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I saw this plant when I was on my trip to the Ukraine.

I wonder if those berries are edible.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I noticed you asked the answer writer how they knew what it was. Check out my post over on The Great Outdoors StackExchange ([Plant identification methods](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/19595/6401)) to get an idea of how to best go about IDing unknown plants using primarily the internet!  (And it just so happens that my post is *also* in reference to a *Phytolacca* plant!!!) 0.o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is of [Phytolacca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytolacca) genus plant which could be toxic for mammals, DO NOT eat as is - it should be cooked properly to be usable/edible (the older, the more toxic leaves are).

Phytolacca acinosa:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there some sort of plant dictionary which can help identify plant species? Or did you just know what it was?

Comment: @TeikoAbe It is easily traceable - you should learn what Inflorescence is - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflorescence and what Venation is - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaf#Venation_.28arrangement_of_the_veins.29, from there it is very simple to know any specific plant.